# Add a line to a surface plot at a particular z value

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to draw a line at z=0.5 for the following `surf` plot. The code is simple enough but now I want to include a line in the `surf` plot at 0.5 for example. My parameters are `Xq`, `Yq` and `Vq`, which I input into the `surf` command of MATLAB. `Xq`, `Yq` and `Vq` are all 2001x4001 matrices produced by `meshgrid`. I find the points in `Vq` equal to 0.5 given a particular tolerance, and I get out of the `find` command with and x and y coordinate, but I am lost from here on out.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`contour3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour3.html) to draw a line where your surface is equal to 0.5. You can specify that you want the 3D line where `Vq` is 0.5 by using the fourth input argument.

```
% Load in some sample data
[Xq, Yq, Vq] = peaks();

% Plot your surface
surf(Xq, Yq, Vq, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
hold on

% Now plot the 3D contour
contour3(Xq, Yq, Vq, [0.5 0.5], 'k');
```

[image]

If you want to get the `Xq` and `Yq` values that are associated with that contour, you can call `contour3` with an output which will return a [`ContourMatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html#property_ContourMatrix) associated with the contour

```
values = contour3(Xq, Yq, Vq, [0.5 0.5], 'k');
```

Comment: Neat! I just have to much data so I need to find a solution to the black plot